# Return data from moq void method with action with no parameter to function being tested

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I've recently added a new method to my repository as I need to process my database calls in transaction mode and all is working well but now that I'm trying to adjust the unit tests, I'm having a problem.

My new void method (i.e. InTransaction), accepts an `Action` as a parameter where I can just pass a anonymous method to it:

```
myFunction()
{
    MyObject data1 = null;
    MyObject data2 = null;

    UnitOfWork.InTransaction(() => 
    {
         data1 = DoSomething(a,b,c);
         data2 = DoSomething(a,b,c);
         UnitOfWork.Save();
    });

    var isValidData1 = IsValid(data1);
    var isValidData2 = IsValid(data2);
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that I still need data1 and data2 to be set to some value or my IsValid function will bomb out as it does not accept null (simplified explanation btw!).

DoSomething is a private method, it still calls other public functions/methods that are also mocked.

if I call the above code

My DoSomething method are private but they are making calls without this new InTransaction method:

```
myFunction()
{
    MyObject data1 = null;
    MyObject data2 = null;

    data1 = DoSomething(a,b,c);
    data2 = DoSomething(a,b,c);
    UnitOfWork.Save();

    var isValidData1 = IsValid(data1);
    var isValidData2 = IsValid(data2);
}
```

All my mocks work as expected and DoSomething will return data as expected and IsValid will also work as expected.

So moqqing my new InTransaction as:

```
unitOfWork.Setup(uow => uow.InTransaction(It.IsAny<Action>());
```

will moq correctly but the problem is that the rest of `MyFunction` function will fail as `IsValid` expects data1 and data2 to be set to something specific.

I've looked at Callback but I don't think it's suitable for this. I'm using it in other unit tests but these are used on function rather than a void method where I'm allowed to set parameters to various objects.

Any ideas how I can return data from a moq void method that takes in an Action parameter inside the function being tested.

Thanks.

Comment: how\where is your `isValid` function defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action will need to be invoked so that the code behaves as expected

A `Callback` can be used to grab the passed action parameter. From there it can be invoked

```
unitOfWork
    .Setup(_ => _.InTransaction(It.IsAny<Action>())
    .Callback((Action action) => action()); //invoke the action within the callback
```

This will allow

```
//...

    () => {
         data1 = DoSomething(a,b,c);
         data2 = DoSomething(a,b,c);
         UnitOfWork.Save();
    }

//...
```

to be run as it should when the test is exercised.

Comment: Thanks for that! Funny as I had just changed my code to pass the action in the callback and I noticed that I could see all my private variable in action.Target but I didn't know how to set them until I spotted your reply! Thanks again. All is working as expected now!